How to disable Global Protect VPN auto start on macOS?
I have recently had to start using Global Protect VPN on my Mac.
It has a dark pattern of auto-loading on startup in a very intrusive way (popping up VPN login window). Meanwhile it isn't even listed in "Login items", making it impossible to disable from there.
To top it off, Global Protect starts up immediately after I kill the process.
I want it to only start when I ask it to, and be able to kill it again after I no longer need it.
How can I tame this undesired start and continually running application on macOS?

Per this reddit post, run the following (sudo required):
sudo /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c \
  "Add :Palo\ Alto\ Networks:GlobalProtect:PanSetup:Portal string vpn.domain.com" /Library/Preferences/com.paloaltonetworks.GlobalProtect.settings.plist
sudo /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c \
  "Set :RunAtLoad false" /Library/LaunchAgents/com.paloaltonetworks.gp.pangpa.plist
sudo /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c \
  "Set :KeepAlive false" /Library/LaunchAgents/com.paloaltonetworks.gp.pangpa.plist
sudo /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c \
  "Set :RunAtLoad false" /Library/LaunchAgents/com.paloaltonetworks.gp.pangps.plist

I tested it and it works for me on macOS 14.5 with app version v6.1.4-711 in June 2024.

On macOS 15.0+, the first command might exit with an error saying Add :Palo\ Alto\ Networks:GlobalProtect:PanSetup:Portal Entry Already Exists. Just change Add to Set. Also, this time Palo Alto Networks do appear in Loging Items and turning the switch off on it will finally kill this damn app.
